# Вывод имен программы на форму

Tags: c++, переменные, вывод, имена

Необходимо ввести любые переменные в программу и вывести в консоль либо на форму их имена. К примеру: объявили мы int a, string b, char p. Должно вывестись: a,b,p. Как это сделать на с++? в c# для этого есть функция nameof(), но в плюсах нет такого аналога.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024648/retrieving-a-c-class-name-programatically

Comment: Можно использовать макро #define `STR(var) #var << '=' << var`

Answer (score 2):

Рефлексия в C++ не поддерживается.

Встречный вопрос - если вы вводите переменную, то вы знаете ее имя. Логично? Значит, можете просто вывести его руками, нет? :)

Еще вариант - через макросы, типа

```
#define DEF(type, var) type var; string var##_name = #var;
```

Но, вообще говоря, не вижу особого смысла этого действа в компилируемом, не интерпретируемом языке. Ведь после сборки программы имен все равно нет, только адреса :)